# Owncloud upgrade fails with MySQL timeout

Tags: mysql, owncloud

I just upgraded to a new Owncloud version. After installing the .deb package, I ran

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ upgrade
```

which gave me:

```
 oc_appconfig                             
  1/24 [=>--------------------------]   4%Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred while executing 'SET unique_checks=1':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
Update failed
```

An online research indicated this was possibly a MySQL timeout issue, so I created `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with the following content:

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=86400
wait_timeout=86400
max_allowed_packet=521M
```

Then I restarted MySQL and retried—to no avail. Most of the times step 1 fails; sometimes I get as far as step 3 (always with the same SQL command timing out).

OS is Raspbian, running on a Raspberry Pi 3.

What will fix this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

can mean a couple of things: Often it refers to a timeout, which can be rectified by increasing the timeout values (default is 8 hours), or indicates that the allowed packet size was exceeded, which can be corrected by increasing `max_allowed_packet`. **It also occurs when the MySQL server crashes in the middle of the operation**, so check for that when the first two options provide no relief.

After some more research, I consulted the MySQL log. There was an empty file named`/var/log/mysql.err`, as well as some files which indicate log rotation.

Running `ps -ef | grep mysql` then gave me the full command line for the MySQL process, with a parameter for the log file, which turned out to be `/var/lib/mysql/<hostname>.err`.

Examining this file revealed that MySQL kept crashing due to data corruption, probably affecting the `oc_filecache` table. This explains why the update failed—how to recover from the corruption will be a [separate question](https://superuser.com/q/1229612/292907). The string displayed by occ above the progress bar seems to be the table which was being processed when the error occurred (if that is unclear from the MySQL logs, where one needs to look close to find the table).

Answer (score 0):

The server probably dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone terribly wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix that, you need to increase the maximal packet size limit `max_allowed_packet` in my.cnf file, then restart MySQL server: (/etc/init.d/mysql restart).

Comment: That is a frequent cause of the error described above but was not the case here (see my answer below). Taken literally, the error message just means that the server has stopped responding—it may have dropped the request, or it may have crashed, possibly the network link may have been interrupted or others.

Comment: A crash should be more detectable compared to a connection closing, though. Links are also easy to spot if they interrupt.